# Twice yearly recuring tasks in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

How to create two recurrence of the same event in a year. For example, one on 1st Jan and 2nd on 1st Jul (6 months after) in Microsoft Outlook 2013?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a task as recurring, you can choose the base unit (Days/Weeks/Months), and then a count.

Just choose 'Months' and '6':

[image]